# A weird case of if else statement malfunction in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

I've been working over this question for a few hours and really hope im not missing anything basic. I know its mostly code but all the information is in comments within the code.

I have a function which i feed in my case:
`$db` is array with access creds
`$uid` is null in this case
`$email` is a valid email address
`$companyid` is a valid specific numeric value, which is irrelevant
`$fname, $lname, $mname, $role` - valid strings

Now the function itself:

```
function hire_employee($db, $uid, $email, $companyid, $fname, $lname, $mname, $role){
    try{    
        $srvr = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db['server'].";dbname=".$db['db'], $db['mysql_login'], $db['mysql_pass'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
        $srvr->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if (is_numeric($uid)){ //uid is null in our case, so we skip this piece of code
            echo "<br>trace 1";//does not output
            $set=$srvr->prepare("INSERT into roles (uid, companyid, role, assigned_date) VALUES ((SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid=:uid and active=1), :companyid, :role, CURDATE());");
            $set->bindParam(":uid", $uid);
            $set->bindParam(":companyid", $companyid);
            $set->bindParam(":role", $role);
            if ($set->execute()){
                return true;
            }
        } elseif (isset($email)) {// this is our case, we have a valid email
            echo "<br>trace 2";//does output
            $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                //is a valid email address
                //first trying to add existing user (if exists)
                echo "<br>trace 2.1";//does output
                $check=$srvr->prepare("INSERT into roles (uid, companyid, role, assigned_date) VALUES ((SELECT uid FROM users WHERE email=:email and active=1), :companyid, :role, CURDATE());");
                $check->bindParam(":companyid", $companyid);
                $check->bindParam(":role", $role);
                $check->bindParam(":email", $email);
                //NOW THE WEIRD PART!!!-----------------------
                if ($check->execute()){//checking if statement executes successfully and returns true
                    echo "<br>trace 2.1.1";//does not output, a proper thing in our case
                    return true;
                } else { //nope user does not exist, we need to create a user
                    echo "<br>trace 2.1.2";//this does not output either!!!
                    //dear stackoverflow member can skip the rest of the code below
                    echo "<br>traceYO!!! $uid, $email, $companyid, $fname, $lname, $mname, $role";
                    $newuserid=register_user($db, $fname, $mname, $lname, "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", true, $email, "NULL");
                    echo $newuserid;
                    if (!is_numeric($newuserid) AND ($newuserif > 0)) {
                        echo "<br>trace 2.1.2.1";
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        echo "<br>trace 2.1.2.2";
                        $insert=$srvr->prepare("INSERT into roles (uid, companyid, role, assigned_date) VALUES (:uid, :companyid, :role, CURDATE());");
                        $insert->bindParam(":uid", $newuserid);
                        $insert->bindParam(":companyid", $companyid);
                        $insert->bindParam(":role", $role);
                        if ($insert->execute()){
                            echo "<br>trace 2.1.2.2.1";
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //is not a valid email address
                return false;
            }
        } else { 
            echo "<br>trace 3";
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        report_error($db, $_SESSION['uid'], $companyid, 'hire_employee', "companyid: $companyid, fname: $fname, mname: $mname, lname: $lname, email: $email, uid: $uid, role:$role", $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the only output I'm getting here:

trace 2
trace 2.1

Somehow it fails to trace 2.1.1 or 2.1.2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: Try to reduce this to a simpler problem. This is way too much code to dump down.

Comment: @Don'tPanic E_ALL is enabled, i have NOTHING in the logs and no errors are thrown

Comment: @Carcigenicate you dont have to go below `//dear stackoverflow member can skip the rest of the code below`

Comment: Most likely either `prepare()` or `execute()` crashes.

Comment: @RWS It's good practice to only post relevant code. Realize that people probably look at your question for only a few seconds before deciding if it's worth their time. If half your question is a packed chunk of code, a lot of people won't see it as worth the effort. Plus, it's fairly common to solve your problem while trying to reduce the code.

Comment: It's probably failing before the if statement and after you `echo "<br>trace 2.1"`

Comment: Perhaps the prepare is failing? Try an echo after the prepare, and check for errors.

Comment: You can also try turning of emulate prepares, then it will throw an error in that case, since you have set ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.

Comment: I got it just right after i finished my last comment, switched off pc and went home after 10 straight hours of coding. As @Don'tPanic mentioned, im working in exception mode. The `catch{}` contains a funny function `report_error($someargs)` which stores inputs, user creds and errors in the database. Due to my stupidity i totally ignored i was having new strings added there with the name of erring function. If i wasnt in exception mode, there would be no way i would miss it.  `if ($check->execute())` generates and exception and its CAUGHT before function returns anything!

Comment: Everyone gets +1 for participating and banging your heads against the wall with me.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I totally agree, and try not to post tons of code. But sometimes the devil is in the detail and in wasn't sure what was wrong over here.

Comment: You learned an important lesson today - creating complex code bites you in the ass when you need to debug it. Complex isn't smart code, complex means a bunch of noise shoved down into a single function that tries to do everything. You can't even test that. There's a reason why people try to write simple code and provide unit tests. And your code is a perfect example of what never to do. I'm going to save it for showing, I just wanted to say thanks for that snippet and good luck with this. If I were you, I'd just shoot that code and start anew.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your kind remark. I really do tend to overcomplicate things. However I normally create functions or methods in a way to perform as much a simple task as possible and if needed i can wrap those functions/methods into yet another function when complexity is needed. While i don't claim that the provided code is even near perfect, I don't really see how to simplify it. The abundance of if() statements does not really confuse me here. In fact, if should I had created multiple functions with this one, I would still have the same issue and would address the hivemind for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it. This line `if ($check->execute())` generated the error exception which got CAUHGT right away thus preventing the function from further execution. I actually saw errors being added where I decided I wanted them to be, however, being a noob with exceptions, I didn't put two and two together. I changed `ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` and it seems to work fine. I get a warning, the `execute()` does not return `true` and the function goes as intended.

I would be really grateful if someone showed me how to catch warnings though.

Anyway, thanks everyone!

#### UPD_1:

Allowing any warnings to be generated is a very bad practice and I'm adjusting the function and or statement accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't catch warnings . Neither you should use PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING

Comment: @YourCommonSense I couldn't agree more, I'm reconsidering the whole function and/or statement.